# Need to resolve a trasient on the Output of power supply

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I am designing a fly-back SMPS AC/DC topology power supply, i mount the PCB and when i tested it with a restive load (hot air stove 230V@600Watt-50Hz) y see that on the DC output appears a transient that reset the micro controller.

The block diagram are as follows:

**AC INPUT-> Fly-back output 5V -> LDO 3.3V regulator -> Micro controller-Oscilloscope probe.**

The transient as the oscilloscope show, inst just one transient pulse, its a number of consecutive transients in a short period of time.

Somebody can help to resolve the problem, i need to maintain the 3.3V to avoid the reset of the micro controller, or at least 2.8V, the photos of the Oscilloscope output are:

***Ideas:***

I am thinking on use a Zener diode to clamp the high part of the transient to 3.6V (to charge a few energy on the capacitor on the high side transient wave), and then a tantalum capacitor to avoid the 1.23V minimum voltage. This capacitor must be fast to charge because the next transient will happen after 2 uS as we see on the oscilloscope image. But... will it be charged enough in this short period of time?.

Or maybe a filter delete it?, i dont have so much practice with they to think how to use to fix the problem.

[image]

**Circuit AC/DC:**
[image]

**3.3V LDO circuit:**

[image]
**Oscilloscopes Images:**

**TOP:**
[image]

**BOT:**
[image]

**TOP-BOT:**
It have some errors in text, like the one i put on the relay... isnt the hall sensor. On the new version i am trying to make it will be fixed.
[image]

**TOP-3D:**
[image]

**BOT-3D:**
[image]

[image: Pulse finish to start.]

[image: Complete transient]

Comment: Adding the zenerdiode will probably not help as the supply voltage appears to **drop** far below 3.3 V, that can trigger the brown-out detection of the uC and causing a reset. The gigantic variations of your 3.3 V supply voltage leads me to believe that your 3.3 V supply simply **isn't good enough** to deliver the current (while maintaining 3.3 V) that is needed. You should provide more details of how that 3.3 V is made, show the circuits etc.

Comment: Sure, uploading the Circuits, if you need some more things just ask me.

Comment: What’s your decoupling situation for the MCU?

Comment: Hi winny, it have 2 ceramic capacitors X5R rated at 6.3V with 10uF.

Then, as the datasheets recommend, it have a pull-up resistor with a capacitor rated at 6.3V X5R on the Enable pin.

VCC-> Resistor -> Enable pin -> Capacitor -> GND

Comment: Where are the 10 uF capacitors located? Also, please show your layout with ground plane.

Comment: The most near possible of the VCC pins, i use Vias to ground it always. Updated with the request photos Winny.